# App_Code Folder turns into App_Code.dll when published

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I was able to publish my website but I get this error when I try to generate a Crystal Report:

> Unable to find the report in the manifest resources. Please build the project, and try again

Upon checking on published folder, I am unable to see the `app_code` folder which contains the RPT files but i am seeing `app_code.dll` in bin folder but I don't know how this dll works. How can I resolve this??

Comment: Can you check this when you are publishing your project make sure that two check boxes under tab `Settings` `Precompile during publishing` and `Exclude files from the App_Data folder` are unchecked.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Can't find that. Am using this publish and this is the only available publish option. http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=publish+web+site+visual+studio+2012&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4qIeDnLfRAhUHwbwKHUi_BHUQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.winhost.com%2Fkb%2Fa1093%2Fhow-to-deploy-visual-studio-2012-web-site-project-to-winhost-server-using-publish-web-site-feature.aspx&psig=AFQjCNFfXnr1Ir4HZNbhLIK5dHPBiCPhDA&ust=1484125352943276

Answer (score 0):

Try to Host your website without publish (For testing only). Host all files as it is in Visual Studio. If problem exists then check your code before publishing.

Comment: Hi, by Host your website you mean to just copy the whole solution in c:.inetpub/wwwroot? I tried that and was able to access my site and generate report without error.

Comment: On Publishing Website, Ensure to check precompile during publishing and on configure check "do no merge.Create separately assembly for each page and control in Setting.